# Error in importing data into the listview with Jsoup

Tags: javascript, android

I'm importing data into the listview with jsoup. It's not working on different url . where as html page is same.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {

                for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Elements tds = row.select("td");
                    map.put("population", tds.get(1).text());

                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: There is no table in second url just text.

Comment: is there any errors being produced? if so could you provide them?

Comment: @roy james-Sir Simple blank activity is showing when i use second url.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and seeing what is being returned from url?